# Navigate from Background operation

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a page in my application which displays, and I would like to perform a potentially long running background operation. Whilst this operation is in progress, another view should be presented, and once complete, the region should be navigated back to its former view. In the case of anything going wrong, navigation should go to some other view.

To illustrate this, assume I have some class, and set an ICommand in its constructor:

```
SomeAction = new DelegateCommand(() =>
{
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyTarget", nameof(SomeProgressPage));

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DoSomeWork();
    });
});
```

The task itself is concerned with something potentially long-running; Once complete it should navigate to a conditional destination.

```
private void SomeWork()
{
    try
    {
        // Do Work
        // ...

        // Return when done.
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyTarget", nameof(SomePage));
    }
    catch
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyTarget", nameof(SomeErrorPage));
    }
}
```

Whilst I can step through this in debug, and not encounter any errors on the way, RequestNavigation doesn't seem to have any effect when called from another thread, nor does it throw an exception. I do navigate to 'SomeProgressPage', the task does run, and based on its outcome, the execution can be followed to RequestNavigation - then nothing.

I have also tried to perform this navigation via events, such as:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<NavigationRequestEvent>().Subscribe(x =>
{
    regionManager.RequestNavigate(x.Target, x.Destination, x.Parameters);

}, ThreadOption.UIThread);
```

In this case, the subscriber isn't even called when the event is published.

I have been unable to find any credible resources on dealing with this from my googling, and short of connecting to the source and debugging through Prism; how should this sort of feature be implemented best whilst using Prism?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open a new window from another thread you need to invoke Current dispatcher.

```
    private void SomeWork()
            {
                try
                {
                    // Do Work
                    // ...

                    // Return when done.
                   App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                    {

                    _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyTarget", nameof(SomePage));

                    });
                }
                catch
                {
                  App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                    {

                    _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyTarget", nameof(SomeErrorPage));

                    });
                }        
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that exceptions thrown in a task that's not awaited are swallowed by the task AggregatedException handler. You can Access the exceptions thrown by a task by checking the Task.Exception property. You can also do the following:

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //DoSomeWork();
        })
        .ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            // Return when done.
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyTarget", nameof(SomePage));
        })
        .ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyTarget", nameof(SomeErrorPage));
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

The second ContinueWith is only lauched when the Task is faulted (meaning that the task has thrown an exception).